# Convert .csv to .txt

Tags: vb.net, csv, text-files

Im currently working on a project. I have a large .csv file and I would like to convert it to .txt file that didn't readable in a file player ( like a binary file).

The reason i want to do it is to protect my data.

Someone told me about encryption, is that it is a good idea? If so, does anyone have a good link?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How about this: just change the file extension from your file explorer.

Comment: CSV **are** text files.  it just so happens the extension .CSV is registered to Excel usually, so clicking them opens them in it.  Any text editor can read an write them,

Comment: Read your .csv as text format file

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it makes no sense.

Comment: Well, let me explain it! I misspoke, im sorry! I want to take my .csv file and convert it to a text file that is not readable in "clear" in a file player. I want to protect my data and dont let the consumer see all the data! So yeah maybe i didn't explain correctly myself. It is not necessary to close my question! 

For now, i did a lot of research about binary file it could be a good option but maybe someone would have a better option?

I am sorry for not being clear!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking the following:

Q:
I have a CSV file whose contents I wish to keep private.
The file is stored on a non-secure device and, being a CSV, is easily read.
How do I prevent others from reading this file?

A:
Encrypt the file.
The GPG tool suite is a good choice for many types of encryption.
https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x110.html

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has an article that details how to encrypt and decrypt files. I would start here.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301070